# H2 Database Corruption Issue and Its Large File Size

Tags: java, database, nullpointerexception, h2

I am using embedded version of H2 1.4.191 with the following connection string:

```
jdbc:h2:<Path of database file>
```

I am facing two problems:

1. Sometimes my database size goes beyond 10GB and system stops working. I think the data stored in db should not take more than 5Mb. What is consuming memory?
2. Sometimes I am getting these exception :

   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: File corrupted while reading record: null. Possible solution: use the recovery tool [90030-191]
       at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
       at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
       at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$Store.convertIllegalStateException(MVTableEngine.java:195)
       at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$Store.open(MVTableEngine.java:167)
       at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine.init(MVTableEngine.java:99)
       at org.h2.engine.Database.getPageStore(Database.java:2460)
       at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:692)
       at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:270)
       at org.h2.engine.Database.(Database.java:264)
       at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:65)
       at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:175)
       at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:153)
       at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:136)
       at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:28)
       at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:349)
       at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.(JdbcConnection.java:107)
       at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.(JdbcConnection.java:91)
       at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72)
       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
       at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcConnectionSource.makeConnection(JdbcConnectionSource.java:252)
       at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcConnectionSource.getReadWriteConnection(JdbcConnectionSource.java:184)
       at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.doCreateTable(TableUtils.java:440)
       at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.createTable(TableUtils.java:220)
       at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(TableUtils.java:61)
       at com.limetray.pos.dbmanagers.DAO.init(DAO.java:75)
       at com.limetray.pos.dbmanagers.DAO.createDB(DAO.java:172)
       at com.limetray.pos.controllers.MainApp.appInitialization(MainApp.java:91)
       at com.limetray.pos.controllers.MainApp.init(MainApp.java:80)
       at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:841)
       at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: File corrupted in chunk 1703, expected check value 1190, got 2040 [1.4.191/6]
       at org.h2.mvstore.DataUtils.newIllegalStateException(DataUtils.java:773)
       at org.h2.mvstore.Page.read(Page.java:667)
       at org.h2.mvstore.Page.read(Page.java:195)
       at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.readPage(MVStore.java:1939)
       at org.h2.mvstore.MVMap.readPage(MVMap.java:736)
       at org.h2.mvstore.Page.getChildPage(Page.java:217)
       at org.h2.mvstore.Cursor.min(Cursor.java:129)
       at org.h2.mvstore.Cursor.hasNext(Cursor.java:36)
       at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.loadChunkMeta(MVStore.java:689)
       at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.readStoreHeader(MVStore.java:670)
       at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.(MVStore.java:353)
       at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$Builder.open(MVStore.java:2888)
       at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$Store.open(MVTableEngine.java:154)

and

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.NullPointerException" [50000-178] 
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:344) 
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:167) 
        at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:294) 
        at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:293) 
        at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:256) 
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:57) 
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:164) 
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:142) 
        at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:125) 
        at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:150) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) 
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
        at org.h2.mvstore.DataUtils.parseMap(DataUtils.java:630) 
        at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.openMap(MVStore.java:411) 
        at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore.<init>(TransactionStore.java:96) 
        at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$Store.<init>(MVTableEngine.java:161) 
        at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine.init(MVTableEngine.java:94) 
        at org.h2.engine.Database.getPageStore(Database.java:2355) 
        at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:659) 
        at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:262)
```

I think both are related to db corruption issue which is there in H2. How should I avoid this issue ? If not, Can I recover my data ?

Comment: What are you inserting exactly to get to 10Gb? 
is it the database file that grows or the log file?

Can you post an example of code you use to make it grow?

Comment: The data I am inserting is too less, I thinks its the issue with how H2 stores data in memory and then flushes it.